# Motion blur makes whole scene completely blurred

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, camera, ocean-simulation, motion-blur

I followed a tutorial from "Blender Made Easy" of a stormy ocean scene https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oysCSbhXYBo&t=2s&ab_channel=BlenderMadeEasy

When I render the animation, the motion blur makes the whole scene blurred. Majority of the 400frame render looks like this [image]

The camera has a location constraint to a plane shrinkwrapped to the ocean surface. When I render without motion blur it looks fine but not as realistic. I have tried fiddling with the motion blur settings, changing it from centre on frame to start or end onframe but the result is the same as if there was no motion blur applied. Here is the settings for motion blur that I've used
[image]

Any help would be much appriciated! here is the full clip https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jdGnZiX166iwy-Oq-9xyoRhbJ6UATuft/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show your complete rendered output?

Comment: Updated with a link to the clip at the end of the post :) Thanks